# Computing Growth of a Variable in R

Tags: r, rate

I want to compute a growth variable in a data frame with R.

Lets say I have a starting variable `X=100` 
and a vector `Y` of time length 10 with growth rates f.e

```
Y<-c(0.04, 0.03, -0.02 ... 0.02)
```

Is there a solution to compute the growth rate of X o.v.t., so that I get a vector for my starting value X, e.g. : (100, 100*(1+0,04), (100*(1+0,04)*(1,03),... etc)

I hope I could make it clear.

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look into `X*cumprod(1+Y)`

Answer (score 0):

Great and easy answer from @AEF in the comments above.
Just posting another solution using `purrr` package and function `accumulate`. Maybe a bit too much for your specific example, but useful if you wanted to apply a more complex function/pattern/methodology:

```
library(purrr)

# set of growth rates
gr_rates = c(0.04, 0.03, -0.02, 0.02)

# function to apply the general formula
f = function(x,r) {x*(1+r)}

# apply the function recursively and show intermediate results
# set the starting point as 100
accumulate(gr_rates, f, .init = 100)

# [1] 100.0000 104.0000 107.1200 104.9776 107.0772
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the cumprod function. This is akin to calculating wealth indexes in finance. Try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame( changes = c(0.04, 0.03, -0.02, 0.02) ) %>% tbl_df()

# Now calculate your growth rates, or wealth indexes, as follows:

start_value <- 100

df_growth_rate <- df %>% mutate( growth_rate = start_value * cumprod(1 + changes))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across that problem computing the growth of an input value for an accounting class. I wrote the following function. It takes the starting value as an input (`x`), the number of period you need to grow that value (`n`) as well as the growth rate (`g`). You could apply that function growth-rate wise to your value `x = 100`.

```
growth_fct <- function(x, n, g){

  xrep <- rep(x, (n-1))
  for(i in seq_along(xrep)){
    xrep[i] <- xrep[i] * (1 + g)^i
  }
  x <- c(x, xrep)
  return(x)
}
```